# R: Using "group_by" with "nls()"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, nls, broom

I have a dataset that I want to fit a Gompertz model grouped by 4 different factors (subject, race, target & distractor). The Gompertz model works when applied to the entire data set (i.e., without applying "group_by"). The group_by function works when I use a (much simpler) linear regression. However, when I try to use group_by with the Gompertz model I get the following error:

```
Error in chol2inv(object$m$Rmat()) : 
  element (3, 3) is zero, so the inverse cannot be computed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nls(yt ~ ymin + ymax * (exp(-exp((alpha * 2.718282/ymax) * (lambda -  :
  Convergence failure: false convergence (8)
2: In nls(yt ~ ymin + ymax * (exp(-exp((alpha * 2.718282/ymax) * (lambda -  :
  Convergence failure: singular convergence (7)
```

Here is the code:

```
grouped_data = all_merged %>%
  group_by(subject,race,target,distractor)

gomp_fits = do(grouped_data, tidy(nls(yt ~ ymin+ymax*(exp(-exp((alpha* 2.718282/ymax)*(lambda-time)+1))), data = ., start = list(lambda = 0.480, alpha = 5.8, ymin = 0, ymax = 1.6),
                                 control = list(warnOnly = TRUE),
                                 algorithm = "port",
                                 lower = c(0,-Inf, -Inf, 0),
                                 upper= c(2, Inf, Inf, 2))))
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are grouping by 4 different variables and trying to fit a 4 parameter model.  Are you sure you have enough samples (> 5) in every group to perform a fit?

Comment: If you do have sufficient data then try using the overall values obtained from the ungrouped nls as the starting values for each group.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

Consider nlsLM, a self-starting Gompertz model or use a method to calculate starting values, use it in a group_modify workflow.

Maybe something like this (though upper and lower limits may not be necessary

```
fit_gomp <- function(data, ...) {
    nlsLM(formula = y ~ SSgompertz(x, Asym, b2, b3),
          data = data,
          lower = c(0,-Inf, -Inf, 0),
          upper = c(2, Inf, Inf, 2),
          ...) %>% tidy()
}

data %>%
  group_by(subject, race, target, distractor) %>%
  group_modify(~ fit_qomp(data = .x), .keep = TRUE)
```

### Getting starting values

While I haven't used a Gompertz model, consider if you can find a way to get starting values mathematically.

For example, let's say I want to fit a quadratic-plateau model (it only has 3 starting parameters however). First I have a function that defines the equation, which will go inside `nls` later.

```
# y = b0 + b1x + b2x^2
# b0 = intercept
# b1 = slope
# b2 = quadratic term
# jp = join point = critical concentration

quadp <- function(x, b0, b1, jp) {
    b2 <- -0.5 * b1 / jp
    if_else(
        condition = x < jp,
        true  = b0 + (b1 * x) + (b2 * x * x),
        false = b0 + (b1 * jp) + (b2 * jp * jp)
    )
}
```

The second part is to make a fitting function that fits a quadratic polynomial, uses those coefficients as starting values in the nls portion, and fits the nls model.

```
fit_quadp <- function(data, ...) {
    # get starting values from simple quadratic
    start <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE), data = data)
    start_values <- list(b0 = start$coef[[1]], # intercept
                         b1 = start$coef[[2]], # slope
                         jp = median(data$x)) # join-point
    
    # nls model that uses those starting values
    nlsLM(formula = y ~ quadp(x, b0, b1, jp),
        data = data,
        start = start_values,
        ...
    ) %>% tidy()
}
```

The `...` is to add arguments for nls.control if needed.

### Analyzing grouped data

As for analyzing grouped data, I use `group_modify()` because it returns a data frame whereas `group_map()` returns a list. So my basic workflow looks like:

```
dataset %>%
    group_by(grouping_variable_1, grouping_variable_2, ...) %>%
    group_modify(~ fit_quadp(data = .x), .keep = TRUE)
```

Then out comes a table with all the tidy statistics because `tidy()` was used in the function. You can consider including a `try()` wrapped around the `nls()` portion of the function so that if it succeeds on the first two groups but on the third, it'll still continue and you should still get some results.

### nlsLM()

Also, if you want to use `nlsLM` from `minpack.lm`, the algorithm there succeeds more than those available in `nls()`. Some worry about false convergence, but I haven't seen it yet in my applications. Also with `nlsLM` you may not need to bother with upper and lower limits, though they can still be set.